# c++で作成されたdll内の関数とC#プログラム間のポインタの取り扱い

Tags: c#, c++, ポインタ, dll

c++で作成されたdll関数とC#のプログラム間の引数のやり取りについてです。

現在、c++で構築されているソフトウェアのデータ取得ツールをc#を用いて作成しています。
プログラムの流れはgetTablePtr()でテーブルへのポインタを取得し、getValFromTable()でテーブル内のデータを取得するものです。
ただし、getValFromTable()は実際はもっと複雑でテーブルのデータが読めれば良いわけではありません。

c++のプログラム、C#のプログラムはそれぞれ下記のように実装しており、getTablePtr()は（正しく使用できているかは別にして）呼び出しができているようで、ptrTに値は入ります。
ところがgetValFromTable()の呼び出しでツールのウィンドウが固まってしまい、その後エラーなどの音沙汰なくウィンドウが閉じてしまいます。

現時点ではどちらの関数も呼び出し自体はできていて、C#でポインタを扱うという点の理解が浅いがためにちぐはぐな実装を行ってしまっているのではないかと思っています。
下記のプログラムをベースにMSのドキュメントなども見ながら引数やIntPtrの使い方を何パターンも試してみましたが、全く歯が立ちそうにありません。

C#で下記のプログラムを正しく実装するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

※関数名がc++側とc#側で異なっていたので修正しました。
（c#側でrefTable → getValFromTable）
※構造体名も中途半端に変更前後のものが混在していたので揃えました。
（STRC → TBL、ptrStrc → ptrTable、ptrS → ptrT）
せっかく見ていただいているのにサンプルコードががばがばで申し訳ないです。
回答いただいている点は一つずつ確認していきます。

---

**C++プログラム**

```
// データテーブル
typedef struct{
    unsigned long v[0x10];
}TBL;

// テーブルのポインタ取得
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TBL* getTablePtr()
{
    TBL* ptrTable;
    /* 処理 */
    return(ptrTable);
}

// テーブルからデータ取得
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LONG  getValFromTable(TBL* ptrTable)
{
    /* 処理 */
    return(val);
}
```

**C#プログラム**

```
class testDLL
{
    [DllImport("testDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "getTablePtr")]
    public static extern IntPtr getTablePtr();
    [DllImport("testDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "getValFromTable")]
    public static extern long getValFromTable(IntPtr ptrTable);
}
    
namespace DLLtest
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IntPtr ptrT;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ptrT = testDLL.getTablePtr();
            ret = testDLL.getValFromTable(ptrT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 簡略化しすぎて問題を再現・説明するのに必要な情報が抜け落ちているのでは？ 提示されたソースで問題を再現出来るのでしょうか？ 一般的なC#とC/C++間のパラメータやデータの受け渡しについての情報はこちらあたりでしょう。[プラットフォーム呼び出しによるデータのマーシャリング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke), [クラス、構造体、および共用体のマーシャリング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions), [さまざまな型の配列のマーシャリング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays), [C#のためのC++の配列、構造体、ポインタの変換処理](https://tomosoft.jp/design/?p=4647)

Comment: ちなみに「getValFromTable()の呼び出しでツールのウィンドウが固まってしまい」ということは、「getValFromTable()の先頭にブレークポイントを設定」してもそこまで行かず(あるいはそこで止まらず)に固まるということでしょうか？ その場合「getTablePtr()の中にブレークポイントを設定」した場合と何か違うか比べてみるとかしてみましたか？

Comment: `/*処理*/`のところの詳細がないのでアレですが `STRC*` と `TBL*` が混在していて何が何だかわからないです。というか元 C++ ソース自体がバグっている可能性すらあります。読者のところで再現できるくらいにまともなサンプルを提示してくれないと話は思うように進まないでしょう。

Comment: @kunif
参考になりそうな文献ありがとうございます。すべて確認してみます。dll内の関数についてですがソースコードは閲覧できますが自由に変更、ビルド、デバッグできる環境ではないので確認できません...。ステップインでもdll内は参照できませんでした。現状でわかることとしてはステップ実行で1行ずつ動作を確認してみても当該の`testDLL.getValFromTable()`の行で実行終了してしまうことだけです。

Comment: @774RR
プログラム内の不整合については修正しました。投稿用にテキストエディタで簡略化してから当サイトのエディットボックス内でもいくつか変更をしていたのですが、中途半端になってしまっており申し訳ないです。また、もとのC++プログラム自体はMFCのソフトウェアで動作しています。複数プロジェクトから構成されるソフトで様々なプロジェクトで呼び出しされる関数なので正常に使用できれば外部からの呼び出しも問題ないと考えています。今回そのプロジェクト内のデータを外部から参照するためにdll経由でデータを取得しようとしている次第です。

Comment: manage (C# EXE) コード中から  `SetupDiGetClassDevsW` で unmanage メモリを確保してもらって情報を得て、その中から HID を探し、最後は `SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList` で unmanage メモリを開放する、というコードはオイラのところで問題なく動いています。なのであなたのやりたいことは可能っス。オイラも `CallingConvention` 類の誤りでメモリ破壊しているだけだと推測。でもマーシャラってそんなに脆くないのでそれだけなら `PInvokeStackImbalance` を検出して正しく停止するだけのはずなんだけど。とりあえずすでについている回答に従って修正してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++(LONG) と C#(int) の型の違いもありますが、おそらくは呼び出し規約の相違ではないでしょうか？
少なくとも 32bit プロセスでは呼び出し規約を合わせる必要があります。

C++ 側のコンパイラが示されていませんが、Visual C++ では __cdecl がデフォルトになっています。
対して、.NET側の [DllImport のデフォルトは Winapi = Stdcall です。](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?view=net-5.0#--)
DllImport 属性で CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl を追加するか、C++ 側で __stdcall をつけるかが必要だと考えられます。

```
[DllImport("testDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "getValFromTable", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int refTable(IntPtr ptrStrc);
```

Comment: 指摘の呼び出し規約の指定で正常に動作するようになりました。
てっきりIntPtrの使い方の問題かと思っていたのでサンプルプログラムをかなり簡略化してしまっていましたが、的確な指摘をいただけたようでとても助かりました。
呼び出し規約についてはまだそれほどわかっていませんが、スタックの使い方などに差があるようで正しく指定しなければ正常に動作しない可能性があるということは理解できました。
勉強します。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

質問と無関係でありながら、実は原因かもしれないので指摘します。

C++側

> ```
> extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LONG  getValFromTable(TBL* ptrStrc)
> ```

C#側

> ```
> [DllImport("testDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "func2")]
> public static extern long refTable(IntPtr ptrStrc);
> ```

となっていますが、C#における`long`は64bitです。対してWindows APIの`LONG`やC++の`long`は32bitです。これらデータサイズが誤っていると引数や戻り値の受け渡しが正しく動作しません。

- C++言語 / [Data Type Ranges](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160)
- Windows API / [Windows Data Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)
- C#言語 / [整数数値型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

を確認してください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
指摘の型の修正だけではデバッグ実行時にPInvokeStackImbalanceが発生していましたが、動作は可能になりました。